# Flat XML To Hierarchy XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt-2.0, webmethods

I am working on middleware technology called webmethods (integration tool) and we have a problem statement and need help/guidance here.

We are getting a flat XML as shown below and that XML needs to be converted to a hierarchy structure. The XML contains `ComponentID` and `relatedComponentID` where if `RelatedCompID` is empty or `null`, that would be my parent and if `RelatedCompID` is not `null` that is my child.

So basically its a deep recursion and it can contain *n* number of parent and *n* number of child. As shown below;

```
ComponentID=0001 is the parent
ComponentID=0002 is the parent
ComponentID=003 is the child of parent 0001
```

...and so on. It can have any child and any parent.

Now, we need to convert it into a hierarchical structure

We tried in webmethods flow language and it did not work. We also tried writing in java code and it did not work. Finally we wanted to try in XSLT for which we are not able to generate the right logic

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LineItems>
  <LineItem>
    <ComponentID>0001</ComponentID>
    <RelatedCompID></RelatedCompID>
    <Category>MainComponent</Category>         
  </LineItem>
  <LineItem>
    <ComponentID>0002</ComponentID>
    <RelatedCompID></RelatedCompID>
    <Category>MainComponent</Category>         
  </LineItem>
  <LineItem>
    <ComponentID>0003</ComponentID>
    <RelatedCompID></RelatedCompID>
    <Category>MainComponent</Category>         
  </LineItem>
  <LineItem>
    <ComponentID>003</ComponentID>
    <RelatedCompID>0001</RelatedCompID>
    <Category>SubComponent</Category>            
  </LineItem>
  <LineItem>
    <ComponentID>004</ComponentID>
    <RelatedCompID>0001</RelatedCompID>
    <Category>SubComponent</Category>
  </LineItem>
  <LineItem>
    <ComponentID>055</ComponentID>
    <RelatedCompID>003</RelatedCompID>
    <Category>SubComponent</Category>
  </LineItem>
  <LineItem>
    <ComponentID>066</ComponentID>
    <RelatedCompID>003</RelatedCompID>
    <Category>SubComponent</Category>
  </LineItem>
  <LineItem>
    <ComponentID>777</ComponentID>
    <RelatedCompID>055</RelatedCompID>
    <Category>SubComponent</Category>
  </LineItem>
  <LineItem>
    <ComponentID>008</ComponentID>
    <RelatedCompID>0002</RelatedCompID>
    <Category>SubComponent</Category>
  </LineItem>
  <LineItem>
    <ComponentID>099</ComponentID>
    <RelatedCompID>004</RelatedCompID>
    <Category>SubComponent</Category>
  </LineItem>
  <LineItem>
    <ComponentID>123</ComponentID>
    <RelatedCompID>0002</RelatedCompID>
    <Category>SubComponent</Category>
  </LineItem>
</LineItems>
```

Comment: Is this your _input XML_ or your _output XML_? I don't know, but it'd be important to know... Better specify you input **and** your desired **output** XML.

Comment: I used XSLT 2 as the question is tagged for that version.

Comment: Hi Martin, no no its fine, thanks a lot for the generous help :) that you have provided, as there where few settings in the tool that we are using is causing the error :(, but will sort that out. But indeed thanks a lot for the quick help indeed, this will help us a lot for to progress further. If at any point, i am lost in understanding, will seek your guidance. :)

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT, it seems a simple use of a key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="child" match="LineItem" use="RelatedCompID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <Components>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', '')"/>
      </Components>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="LineItem">
      <Component>
          <xsl:copy-of select="* except RelatedCompID"/>
          <SubComponents>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', ComponentID)"/>
          </SubComponents>
      </Component>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQgn

That transforms your input into

```
<Components>
   <Component>
      <ComponentID>0001</ComponentID>
      <Category>MainComponent</Category>
      <SubComponents>
         <Component>
            <ComponentID>003</ComponentID>
            <Category>SubComponent</Category>
            <SubComponents>
               <Component>
                  <ComponentID>055</ComponentID>
                  <Category>SubComponent</Category>
                  <SubComponents>
                     <Component>
                        <ComponentID>777</ComponentID>
                        <Category>SubComponent</Category>
                        <SubComponents/>
                     </Component>
                  </SubComponents>
               </Component>
               <Component>
                  <ComponentID>066</ComponentID>
                  <Category>SubComponent</Category>
                  <SubComponents/>
               </Component>
            </SubComponents>
         </Component>
         <Component>
            <ComponentID>004</ComponentID>
            <Category>SubComponent</Category>
            <SubComponents>
               <Component>
                  <ComponentID>099</ComponentID>
                  <Category>SubComponent</Category>
                  <SubComponents/>
               </Component>
            </SubComponents>
         </Component>
      </SubComponents>
   </Component>
   <Component>
      <ComponentID>0002</ComponentID>
      <Category>MainComponent</Category>
      <SubComponents>
         <Component>
            <ComponentID>008</ComponentID>
            <Category>SubComponent</Category>
            <SubComponents/>
         </Component>
         <Component>
            <ComponentID>123</ComponentID>
            <Category>SubComponent</Category>
            <SubComponents/>
         </Component>
      </SubComponents>
   </Component>
   <Component>
      <ComponentID>0003</ComponentID>
      <Category>MainComponent</Category>
      <SubComponents/>
   </Component>
</Components>
```

Obviously I had to make some choice for the element names (e.g. `Component`) and structure (e.g. `SubComponents`) in the nested result but you should be able to adjust that to your needs that you did not show in your question.

As you complained about an error due to the use of `except`, that is an XPath 2 operator that should be supported by any XSLT 2 processor, but it is easy to rewrite that expression for XSLT/XPath 1 with a predicate `*[not(self::RelatedCompID)]`, so the XSLT 1 version would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="child" match="LineItem" use="RelatedCompID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <Components>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', '')"/>
      </Components>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="LineItem">
      <Component>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::RelatedCompID)]"/>
          <SubComponents>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', ComponentID)"/>
          </SubComponents>
      </Component>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQgn/3.

As for help to get the exact XML output structure, if you can't figure out how to adapt the code samples in this answer to produce the wanted output then please edit your question and show it there as an XML code sample.